# After Segue can't pass info

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

So i have a problem i prepared my code for Segue and when i am trying to pass an info and calling this info in other view the error.

> use of undeclared identifier 'selectedCellToSegue"

appears

This is how i am passing the info from one view to the other one .

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"])

    //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    NSIndexPath *selectedCellToSegue;
    selectedCellToSegue = selectedCellToPass;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets after the if:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
    //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    NSIndexPath *selectedCellToSegue;
    selectedCellToSegue = selectedCellToPass;
}
```

What your code does is check for the identifier and then declares a variable. That is the only statement dependent on the if. The next line is not in the body of the if and therefore can not access variables defined in its scope.

If you omit the brackets after the if only the exact next statement will be conditionally executed. If you insert brackets, all the code in those brackets gets conditionally executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a handle to the view you are segueing to so you can set its property. Like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]){
        MyDestinationView *vc=[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.myVar=myVar;

    }

}
```